# Getting results out of multiple comboboxes in java?

Tags: java, fxml

I have been looking for an answer to do this; So my project is a program with multiple comboboxes which can have the item "Positive","Negative" and "Unknown".

In the event of every result being negative, the textbox should say that they're good.
In the event of any result being positive, the textbox should say that they need to consult a doctor.
In the event of any result being unknown, the textbox should say that they need to do the test again.

The way  I did it until now was with `cb1.getvalue().equals("Negative")`, but is there a better solutions? In a for-loop perhaps?

My Java-code until now

````
@FXML
    protected TextArea txtResultaat;
    @FXML
    public ComboBox cb1;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb2;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb3;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb4;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb5;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb6;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb7;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb8;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb9;
    @FXML
    public  ComboBox cb10;
    @FXML
    public Button submit;



    public void onNiewPatientClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    @FXML
    public void CheckCombobox(){
        if (cb1.getValue().equals("Negatief") && cb2.getValue().equals("Negatief") && cb3.getValue().equals("Negatief")
                && cb4.getValue().equals("Negatief") && cb5.getValue().equals("Negatief") && cb6.getValue().equals("Negatief")
                && cb7.getValue().equals("Negatief") && cb8.getValue().equals("Negatief")&& cb9.getValue().equals("Negatief")
                && cb10.getValue().equals("Negatief")){
            System.out.println("success");
            txtResultaat.appendText(result 1);
        }
        if (cb1.getValue().equals("Inconclusief") || cb2.getValue().equals("Incoclusief") || cb3.getValue().equals("Inconclusief")
                || cb4.getValue().equals("Inconclusief") || cb5.getValue().equals("Inconclusief") || cb6.getValue().equals("Inconclusief")
                || cb7.getValue().equals("Inconclusief") || cb8.getValue().equals("Inconclusief")|| cb9.getValue().equals("Inconclusief")
                || cb10.getValue().equals("Inconclusief")){
            System.out.println("success");
            txtResultaat.appendText(result 2);
        }
        if (cb1.getValue().equals("Positief") || cb2.getValue().equals("Positief") || cb3.getValue().equals("Positief")
                || cb4.getValue().equals("Positief") || cb5.getValue().equals("Positief") || cb6.getValue().equals("Positief")
                || cb7.getValue().equals("Positief") || cb8.getValue().equals("Positief")|| cb9.getValue().equals("Positief")
                || cb10.getValue().equals("Positief")){
            System.out.println("success");
            txtResultaat.appendText(result 3);
        }

        else{
            System.out.println(cb1.getValue());
            System.out.println(cb2.getValue());
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your components into some `Pane` (e.g. `GridPane`), inject it via `@FXML` and then perform your check with something like this:

```
@FXML
public GridPane comboBoxPane;

@FXML
public void checkCombobox() {
    final List<Node> children = this.comboBoxPane.getChildren();
    if (children.stream().allMatch(comboBox -> ((ComboBox) comboBox).getValue().equals("Negatief")) {
        // All negative
    }
    else if (children.stream().anyMatch(comboBox -> ((ComboBox) comboBox).getValue().equals("Positief")) {
        // At least one positive
    }
    // ...other cases go here
}
```